# how i can fix this socketio probelm

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

**result:**

```
Fatal error:
  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The server returned an unexpected value.
  Expected "HTTP/1.1 101", had "HTTP/1.1 400"
  in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X.php:266
Stack trace:
  #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X.php(73): ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X->upgradeTransport()
  #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Client.php(60): ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X->connect()
  #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\emit.php(12): ElephantIO\Client->initialize()
  #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\wisembly\elephant.io\src\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X.php on line 266
```

**server.js :**

```
const socket = require('socket.io'),
      express = require('express'),
      https = require('https'),
      http = require('http'),
      logger = require('winston');

const app = express();

const http_server = http.createServer(app).listen(3001);

logger.info('server running port 3001');

function emitNewOrder(http_server) {
    var io = socket.listen(http_server);

    io.sockets.on('connection',function (socket) {

        socket.on('new_order', function (data) {
            io.emit("new_order", data);
        });

    });
}

emitNewOrder(http_server);
```

**emit.php :**

```
<?php

include ("vendor/autoload.php");

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version1X;

$version = new Version1X("http://localhost:3001");

$client = new Client($version);

$client->initialize();

$client->emit("new_order", ["test1"=>"test1","test2"=>"test2"]);

$client->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try Version2X instead

```
<?php

include ("vendor/autoload.php");

use ElephantIO\Client;
use ElephantIO\Engine\SocketIO\Version2X;

$client = new Client(new Version2X('http://localhost:3001'));

$client->initialize();
$client->emit("new_order", ["test1"=>"test1","test2"=>"test2"]);
$client->close();
```

Comment: tried this but Version1X.php error still showing

Comment: @James Version1X have issues. Use Version2x